# ASP.NET MVC Model Data is not getting updated

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Here is the link to ASP.NET MVC fiddler: https://dotnetfiddle.net/W5Nr0a
Initially I have 2 records in the output. When I save with 2 records, display.Result.Count() will show 2 as output. When I add rows dynamically( through Add Button), I still get the result as 2.

In my Ajax call, I am serializing the form & sending, why is it not getting updated?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because your calling the action `SaveData`(`@Url.Action("SaveData", "Home")`) in your AJAX request and you don't actually have a `SaveData` action.

You seem to only have `GET` and `POST` actions named `Index`.

I haven't looked at the rest of your code but you should start by creating this action.